# LVM: How to recover LVM thin pool / volume after failed repair?

Tags: lvm, data-recovery, thinpool

I would like some advise with recovering from broken LVM thin pool / volumes. The step that cause my broken LVM thin is as follows:

1. My thin pool metadata was full (99.4%), so the pool freeze.
2. I tried to extend the pool and its metadata using the following 2 commands:

   `lvextend -L+50G vg/pool
   lvextend --poolmetadata +50m vg/pool`
3. At this point lvs show metadata is still stuck at 99.4%
4. I try repairing metadata with lvconvert --repair vg/pool
5. Now my pool seems to be empty, lvs show 0% data for the pool and lv too.
6. I try switch back to metadata before repair with:

   `lvconvert --thinpool vg/pool --poolmetadata pool-meta0`

   and still no data.

Is there anyway I could recover from this? I have quite a few lv in this thin pool that I would like to save.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In my case `lvextend --poolmetadata` didn't allow for any changes, as it would ask me to perform a ***Manual Repair™***. Therefore, I will describe what worked in my situation.

In this scenario all the system partitions are in thinly provisioned Logical Volumes and the entire **LVM is encrypted inside a LUKS** physical partition. Those of you who don't use encryption can skip the `cryptsetup` command at step 2.

---

**1.** Add an extra drive with more storage capacity than your system drive, boot into recovery mode using the Operating System install media and, without mounting any partitions, start a root shell. Try to use a distro with an installer with thin provisioning support and the latest kernel version to increase the chances of success during the recovery process (i.e. Fedora better than CentOS or RedHat).

**2.** Identify and mount your extra drive, perform a backup image of the entire system and mount the encrypted partition:

```bsh
$ fdisk -l                                   #Identify drives and partitions
```

(We will use ***/dev/sda*** for the system drive, ***/dev/sdb*** for the extra drive and ***volname*** for the LUKS encrypted volume name in this example)

```bsh
$ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt                       #Mount the extra drive
$ cd /mnt
$ cat /dev/sda > sda.img                     #Back up the system drive
$ sha256sum /dev/sda > sda.sum
$ sed -i 's/\/dev\/sda/.\/sda.img/g' sda.sum
$ sha256sum -c sda.sum                       #Verify backup integrity
$ cryptsetup open /dev/sda2 volname          #Mount encrypted LVM
```

**3.** At this point some distributions may try to automatically activate the logical volumes, which would keep the `lvs`, `vgs` or `pvs` commands hanging and prevent us from working with the logical volumes. In this step that process is killed and the logical volumes are put into the proper state:

```bsh
$ ps aux | grep scan                         #Look for 'lvm pvscan' or similar
root     1234  0.0  0.0    64843  9472 ?    Ss   11:11   0:02 /usr/sbin/lvm pvscan -a ...

$ kill -9 1234                               #Get the PID and kill it with fire
$ pvscan                                     #Scan without activating volumes
```

(***vg*** and ***pool00*** correspond to the volume group and thin pool names)

```bsh
$ lvchange -an vg                            #Deactivate entire volume group
$ lvchange -pr -ay vg/pool00_tmeta           #Activate metadata in readonly mode
```

**4.** Now it's time to create a new logical volume for the metadata and repair it:

```bsh
$ lvs -a --units m | grep pool00_tmeta       #Get the current metadata size
  [pool00_tmeta]                       vg ewu-ai----    128.00m
    
$ lvcreate -L 256M -n pool00R vg             #Create a larger logical volume
$ lvchange -ay vg/pool00R                   #Activate the new logical volume
$ thin_repair -i /dev/vg/pool00_tmeta -o /dev/vg/pool00R
$ thin_check /dev/vg/pool00R                 #Verify it's been repaired properly
```

**5.** Finally, we replace the metadata logical volume of the thin pool and remove the old one:

```bsh
$ lvchange -an vg                            #Deactivate all LVs again
$ lvconvert --thinpool vg/pool00 --poolmetadata vg/pool00R
$ lvs -a --units m | grep pool00_tmeta       #Verify the LVs have been swapped
  [pool00_tmeta]                       vg ewu-ai----    256.00m

$ lvremove vg/pool00R                        #Get rid of the damaged metadata
```

---

If anything went wrong during the process, you can restore your backup from the extra drive like this:

```bsh
$ cat /mnt/sda.img > /dev/sda
```

Comment: I tried this but got some problems, can you take a look? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292695/how-to-recover-some-files-from-lvm-thinpool-from-qubes-os

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Please, receive my most sincere apologies: when you posted your comment I checked my answer and at first glance couldn't find anything wrong (this is a bit difficult to re-create). Today I found I made a stupid typo at the line `lvchange -ay vg/poool00R` (notice there is an extra "o" in there) probably due to me having to take these notes on a piece of paper. I have already corrected the answer. I am terribly sorry.